# Django widget for a dropdown list

Tags: django, forms, model

Which django widget must be used for a dropdown list? I already have a model which provides a dropdown list. It is, however, necessary to customize the corresponding form element (text and error msg text) and it becomes necessary to specify the widget.

Here is the Model:

```
class ClientDetails(models.Model):
    paymentType = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Zahlungsart', choices=PAYMENT_TYPES)
```

And the Form:

```
class ClientDetailsForm(ModelForm):
    paymentType = forms.???(label='Zahlungsart', error_messages={'required': (u'Waehlen Sie die Zahlungsart!'), 'invalid': (u'Waehlen Sie die Zahlungsart!')})
```

Answer (score 6):

We need to use forms.Select()

```
class Meta:
    model=someForm
    fields=['Dropdown']
    widgets = {
      'Dropdown': forms.Select(attrs={'id':'choicewa'}),
      }
```

Comment: this actually worked like charm but dropdown is a  such disturbing name for form variable

Answer (score 5):

The place you marked by ??? is for specifying [Field class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/). If you want to specify proper field class you should use  [forms.ChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).

Detailed information on widgets and fields:

- [Overriding the default field types or widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets)
- [Specifying widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/#specifying-widgets)

Comment: Ok, that works. Now the field has the first choice preselected instead of showing an unselected option (model => '-----') which then fails to validate if not changed. How to achieve model like behavior with the '----'?