# Adding Drop Down List to forms.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, widget

How do I get a drop down list to appear in a form with a bespoke layout? Once I moved away from Crispy formatting and the standardised form layout, I lost the drop down list.

I found a few solutions for forms.Form but not forms.ModelForm. And I tried modifying the widgets section of forms.ModelForm but that didn't solve my issue.

[image]

```
class HotelSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RoomType
        fields = ['room_type', 'price']
        widgets = {'room_type': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg  select'})}



Room_Type = (
    ('Single','Single'),
    ('Double','Double'),
    ('Family','Family'),
)


class RoomType(models.Model):
    room_type            = models.CharField(choices=Room_Type)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my final solution

```
'room_type': forms.Select(attrs={'id':'RoomTypeDropDownList', 'class':'form-control form-control-lg  select'})}
```

It was based on [MbeforeL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931541/django-widget-for-a-dropdown-list).